# How to enter superscripts and subscripts in the text box

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to type super scripts like `n = 2hu /gb2` here i should get gb squre not two. i want to copy mathematical formulas in text box and want to copy and paste in text box as it is . mathematical symbols are not treating here as mathematical symbols while copying

my aim is to convert `n = 2hu /gb2 to  n = 2hu /gb<sup>2</sup>` in excel sheet

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     lblResult.Text = txtMathSymbol.Text;
 }
```

I'm not getting exact mathematical symbols in labels from text box.

Comment: What is txtMathSymbol.Text set to? What symbol are you expecting to see and what do you see? Currently, your question is very unclear and risks being closed. Please improve it.

Comment: Your textbox needs to support symbols etc and have a means of entering and editing them. Have you looked at rich text formats?

Comment: symbols like square @DavidArno

Comment: in rich text formats square symbol is not there. my problem is i have word doc in that lot of mathematical expressions are there i jsut want to show as it is.@PeterSmith

Answer (score 1):

you can use unicode to enter superscripts and subscripts, like so

```
    Label1.Text = "2" + "\x2080"; // subscript 0
    Label2.Text = "2" + "\x00B2"; // superscript 2
```

the complete list can be found here [unicode](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U2070.pdf)

Comment: i have lot of mathematical symbols in xls document i want to convert all at once , and create new xls doc is it possible @uowzd01

Comment: then you have to use library, look around